# Filter Transform on layered Altair charts error

Tags: python, altair

I want to use multiple drop-down to look at various days of prediction intervals against the actual price of something. I have created the drop-downs and it works individually. However, when I try to layer the charts I get a 'Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "History__tuple"' error.

```
run_list = list(results.runs.unique())
datas = list(results.dataDays.unique())
looks = list(results.looks.unique())
dates = list(results.date.unique())

date_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=dates)
date_select = alt.selection_single(bind=date_dropdown, fields=['date'], name="Day")

look_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=looks)
look_select = alt.selection_single(bind=look_dropdown, fields=['looks'], name="Back Forward_")

data_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=datas)
data_select = alt.selection_single(fields=['dataDays'], bind=data_dropdown, name="History:")

run_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=run_list)
run_select = alt.selection_single(fields=['runs'], bind=run_dropdown, name="Variation:")

domain = [True, False]
range_ = ['#858987', '#C62B0A']

base_sp = alt.Chart(results, 
                 width=835, 
                 height=500
                ).encode(
    x=alt.X('hoursminutes(endtime)', title='Time of Day')    
)

diff_viz = base_sp.mark_point(filled=True, opacity=0.7
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('open', title= 'StockPrice', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    tooltip=['hoursminutes(endtime)','open','looks','runs','dataDays'],
    color = alt.Color('bound_check', scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_),title='In/Out Bounds')
).add_selection(
    data_select,
    look_select,
    run_select,
    date_select
).transform_filter(
    look_select 
).transform_filter(
    data_select
).transform_filter(
    run_select
).transform_filter(
    date_select
).properties(title="Prediction Interval + True StockPrice")

upp_intervals = base_sp.mark_line(
    opacity=0.5, 
    strokeDash=[1,2],
    color='#3655C7', 
    interpolate='monotone'
).encode(
    alt.Y('upper', scale = alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    tooltip=['upper']
).add_selection(
    data_select,
    look_select,
    run_select,
    date_select
).transform_filter(
    look_select 
).transform_filter(
    data_select
).transform_filter(
    run_select
).transform_filter(
    date_select
)

alt.layer(upp_intervals, diff_viz)
```

diff_viz or upp_intervals will plot fine, but layering them gives the Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "History__tuple" error.

```
import vega_datasets as vd

df = vd.data.climate()
df['date'] = [str(x.date()) for x in df['DATE']]

dates = list(df.date.unique())

date_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=dates)
date_select = alt.selection_single(bind=date_dropdown, fields=['date'], name="Day")

base = alt.Chart(df, 
                 width=835, 
                 height=500
                ).encode(
    x=alt.X('hoursminutes(DATE)', title='Time of Day')    
)

temps = base.mark_point(filled=True, opacity=0.7, color='#0766B4', interpolate='monotone'
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('HLY-TEMP-NORMAL', title= 'Hourly Temps', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    tooltip=['hoursminutes(DATE)','HLY-TEMP-NORMAL'],
)

dews = base.mark_point(
    opacity=0.7, 
    filled=True,
    color='#228006', 
    interpolate='monotone'
).encode(
    alt.Y('HLY-DEWP-NORMAL', title='Hourly Dew Point', scale = alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    tooltip=['hoursminutes(DATE)', 'HLY-DEWP-NORMAL']
)

chart = alt.layer(temps, dews).add_selection(
    date_select
).transform_filter(
    date_select
)
```

Comment: Try adding the selections only once, to the final layered chart instead of each individual one. If that doesn't work, please post a [mre]

Comment: @joelostblom please see the amended post above...an example using your suggestion is at the bottom. This attempt yielded an attribute error

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail. If you include  sample of `vd.data.climate()` or use another publicly available data set it will be easier for contributors here to help you since they can copy paste your code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @joelostblom Sorry I forgot to copy the line importing vega_datasets. I used sample data from that package to recreate the example

Comment: I just tried your second example and it works fine for me, no errors. Try upgrading to altair 5+ and see if it works for you too

Comment: @joelostblom Thanks!!! altair 5+ wasn't working for me before, but now that I've gotten it to work it plotted perfectly. Thanks for your help.